How to set an image and text side by side with different width ratio and an identical height
I need to place two div's side by side - left div is of 60% of the screen width and right div to be of the remaining 40%. Height of both the div's to be 90vh.
In the left div, I need to set an image that it should fit without affecting the image's height and width ( I mean that the image needs to be automatically resized to fit the left div)
In the right div, I need the relevant text to be displayed.
Certainly, I need this entire set up to be responsive.
Please see my both HTML and CSS code with which I'm trying. However, the issue I'm facing is that the image is not auto resized - I'm loosing a part of image from the top and bottom as you can see in the attached screenshot.
Please help!
Screenshot


#hero-section{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
}

#image-div{
    width: 60%;
    border: solid black 2px;
}

#hero-image{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;

}


#hero-text{
    width: 40%;
    border: solid black 2px;
}
<body>
    <div id="hero-section">
        <div id="image-div">
            <img id="hero-image" src="ai-generated-8048681_1920.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div id="hero-text">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium quibusdam laboriosam ipsum alias, aliquam voluptatum in earum minus possimus eius commodi nobis natus saepe maiores nesciunt reprehenderit eligendi sequi? Velit?</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>




"I'm loosing a part of image from the top and bottom" - that's what object-fit: cover does: "The replaced content is sized to maintain its aspect ratio while filling the element's entire content box. If the object's aspect ratio does not match the aspect ratio of its box, then the object will be clipped to fit." Do you want the behavior of contain instead? If not, then you need to explain how you actually expect this to behave.

@C3roe. Yes, as you can see, I have already tried the object-fit:cover in my css, but part of the head of the image is cut (clipped) off when it is fit to the div element. I don't want that to happen. I need the full image to be scaled-down and get fit to the element without loosing its part(s). I then tried the "contain", but it leaves white space from both left and right of the image while the image keeps its all aspects. I also tried both "scale-down" and "fill" values, but with them the image is stretched out and distorted. What is the way around to get this done?

Those requirements you are formulating there, make little sense. In cases where the image aspect ratio doesn't match that of the div - you can either have parts of the image cut off, or blank space besides the image. Or you would need to allow for the image to stretch. Or you would need to make sure, that the aspect ratio of the div matches that of the image in the first place - but you can't have that either, with 60% width and 90vh height.

Yes, after researching as much as I can and putting efforts, I also come to conclusion that I somehow need to get the image size as close as to the size of the div element. Can you please tell me what is the pixel sizes of 60% of the width and 90vh? If I know the pixel sizes of this div, then I can try to get my image resized according to those sizes using a software without loosing the parts I'm concerned of.

"Can you please tell me what is the pixel sizes of 60% of the width and 90vh?" - that obviously depends on the viewport size. So no, I can't tell you, because I don't know your viewport size. And you won't know that of your site visitors either (unless you want to involve JavaScript.)

You can try like this:
#hero-image{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}

But this will have some white spaces if the image is not fit.
To address that issue, there is also:

object-fit: fill;, or
object-fit: cover;

Read more about them


#hero-section{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
}

#image-div{
    width: 60%;
    border: solid black 2px;
}

#hero-image{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;

}


#hero-text{
    width: 40%;
    border: solid black 2px;
}
<body>
    <div id="hero-section">
        <div id="image-div">
            <img id="hero-image" src="https://cataas.com/cat" alt="">
        </div>
        <div id="hero-text">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium quibusdam laboriosam ipsum alias, aliquam voluptatum in earum minus possimus eius commodi nobis natus saepe maiores nesciunt reprehenderit eligendi sequi? Velit?</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>



object-fit: fill;


#hero-section{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
}

#image-div{
    width: 60%;
    border: solid black 2px;
}

#hero-image{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: fill;

}


#hero-text{
    width: 40%;
    border: solid black 2px;
}
<body>
    <div id="hero-section">
        <div id="image-div">
            <img id="hero-image" src="https://cataas.com/cat" alt="">
        </div>
        <div id="hero-text">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium quibusdam laboriosam ipsum alias, aliquam voluptatum in earum minus possimus eius commodi nobis natus saepe maiores nesciunt reprehenderit eligendi sequi? Velit?</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>



